# how to get low latency in Exoplayer RTSP live streaming on android?

Tags: rtsp, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am working on RTSP live Streaming. I am getting live stream on my android App using exoplayer RTSP stream player. But latency of that streaming is about 3 seconds. As latency on vlc media player is 1 second. so how to reduce latency in exoplayer. Is there any way please tell me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're facing is `buffering latency`. VLC uses its own engine and buffering algorithms. However, if you wanna reduce buffering latency on `ExoPlayer`, you gotta get yourself familiarized with `LoadControl`. ExoPlayer uses a `DefaultLoadControl` in default instantiation. This LoadControl is a class that belongs to the ExoPlayer library, and it determines the values of time durations the player should spend in order to buffer the stream. If you wanna reduce the delay, you gotta reduce the LoadControl buffer values.

Here's a quick snippet of creating a SimpleExoPlayer instance with a custom load control :

```kotlin
val customLoadControl = DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
                .setBufferDurationsMs(minBuffer, maxBuffer, playbackBuffer, playbackRebuffer)
                .build()
```

**Parameters in a nutshell** : minBuffer is the minimum buffered video duration, maxBuffer is the maximum buffered video duration, playbackBuffer is the required buffered video duration in order to start playing , playbackRebuffer is the required buffered video duration in case it failed and it retries.

In your case, you should set your values really low, especially the `playbackBuffer` and `minBuffer` parameters. You should mess around with small values (they are in **milliseconds**). Going with a value of `1000` for both `minBuffer` and `playbackBuffer`

**How to use the custom load control** : After building the custom load control instance and storing it in a variable, you should pass it when you're building your `SimpleExoPlayer` :

```kotlin
myMediaPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this@MainActivity)
            .setLoadControl(customLoadControl)
            .build()
```

**What to expect**:
Using the default values is always recommended. If you mess with the values, the app may crash, the stream may be stuck, or the player may get very glitchy. So manipulate the values intelligently.

Here is the javadocs [DefaultLoadControl Javadocs](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultLoadControl.html)

***If you don't know what buffering is***, exoplayer (or any other player) may need to buffer (load the upcoming portion of the video/audio and store it in memory, rendered, way faster to access and reduces playback problems. Streamed media however needs buffering because it comes in form of `chunks`. So each chunk that arrives, will eventually be buffered. If you set the required buffered duration to 1000, you are telling ExoPlayer that the first chunk of stream that arrives whose length is 1000 millisecond should be buffered and played right away. I believe there is no simpler way to explain this. Best of luck.